# Create box with title and text in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, entity, case

can I create something like this in silverlight? A box with editable title and the rest of the text

http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/latest/reference/en-US/html/images/remoting-model-customer-address-uml.png

Comment: Hi, it is recommended to show some code that shows what you tried so far and where you got stuck. Such short questions are hard to answer and often receive downvotes and/or get closed quickly. (Commented after seeing your previous questions). - Oh, and please _never_ repost a question. Improve your question in stead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a custom user control:

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.MyBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Header,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                 BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="2" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Text,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap"
                 VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                 AcceptsReturn="True"
                 BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="2" Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MyBox : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Header", typeof(string), typeof(MyBox));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Content", typeof(string), typeof(MyBox));

        public string Header
        {
            get { return GetValue(HeaderProperty) as string; }
            set { SetValue(HeaderProperty, value); }
        }

        public string Text
        {
            get { return GetValue(TextProperty) as string; }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }

        public MyBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = this;
        }
    }
}
```

A sample:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <local:MyBox x:Name="box1" Header="Type a header..." Text="Type a content..." Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="10" />
        <local:MyBox x:Name="box2" Header="Type a header..." Text="Type a content..." Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="10" />
        <Button Content="Show" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Click="Button_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}\n{1}\n\n{2}\n{3}", box1.Header, box1.Text, box2.Header, box2.Text));
        }
    }
}
```

This is **WPF** but should be fine in Silverlight too, except the *MessageBox* stuff but it's only for debugging purposes...

EDIT:
Here is a sample for dynamic generation:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel x:Name="panel" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <local:MyBox x:Name="box1" Header="Type a header..." Text="Type a content..." Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="10" />
        </StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Add" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Click="Button_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

CodeBehind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            panel.Children.Add(new MyBox
            {
                Header = "Another box",
                Text = "...",
                BorderBrush = Brushes.Black,
                BorderThickness = new Thickness(1),
                Margin = new Thickness(10)
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It gives me a error in those "DependencyProperty". And other problem is that in xaml I just can have a button to create the boxes.. the boxes can't be already created when the program starts

Comment: @LuisAmaro The DependencyProperty things should work if you add a `null` parameter to the end of the `Register` call. And you can create the boxes at runtime like this: `var myBox = new MyBox(); myControl.Children.Add(myBox);` where `myControl` is something that displays it (e.g. `StackPanel`, `Grid`, or `Canvas`).

Comment: The error is due to SL having only one overload for Register, to fix it just add a null parameter at the end. The sample only illustrates one use-case for the control, but you can use it as any native SL control.

Comment: yes thanks, i tested and the box worked, but now how can I make more boxes like this just by clicking a button? because i think this is two separated textboxes in xaml (header+text) and i'm guessing I have to do it all in c# .. i'm new at silverlight btw :p

Comment: many thanks, i can create boxes by clicking a button.. now i'm trying to drag and drop these boxes, I tried with a sample code i have from moving rectangles and other objects, but with these i cant

Comment: You should be able to do that with the same kind of code by putting the boxes in a Canvas rather than a StackPanel. If you have any issue open a new question.

Comment: but it gaves me an error saying that this is not recognized as an object

Comment: What is not recognized? And please post a new question this will be easier for speaking and everybody will be able to help you. :)

Comment: do you know how can I save the info from the textboxes to an xml file? can you look at my new question? :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17125665/silverlight-save-textbox-to-xml