# silverlight save textbox to xml

Tags: xml, silverlight, save, export

my project looks like this, http://s23.postimg.org/mrhuocn4b/asd.png

and I already can save a textbox to xml file, using this code:

```
private void SaveFile(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();

        saveFileDialog.DefaultExt = "xml";
        saveFileDialog.Filter = "XML Files (*.xml)|*.xml|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        saveFileDialog.FilterIndex = 1;

        if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {


            using (Stream stream = saveFileDialog.OpenFile())
            {

                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                sw.Write(GetGeneratedXML().ToString());
                sw.Close();

                stream.Close();

            } 

        }
                }


    private XElement GetGeneratedXML()
    {

        XElement userInformation = new XElement("names");
        userInformation.Add(new XElement("first", box1.Text));
       // userInformation.Add(new XElement("last", lastNameText.Text));

        return userInformation;

    }
```

But this is from a textbox already created in XAML (that I used just for testing), and what I want is to save the text's of all the textboxes created by clicking the buttons.

THIS IS HOW I CREATE THE TEXTBOXES:

XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Header,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                 BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Text,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap"
                 VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                 AcceptsReturn="True"
                 BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Row="1" />
```

C#:

```
private void b_ClickEntidade(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyBox c = new MyBox();
            c.Header = "Entidade";
            c.Text = "Atributos";
            c.Margin = new Thickness(10);
            c.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(c);
            c.MouseLeftButtonDown += Handle_MouseDownEntidade;
            c.MouseMove += Handle_MouseMoveEntidade;
            c.MouseLeftButtonUp += Handle_MouseUpEntidade;
            Canvas.SetLeft(c, 250);
            Canvas.SetTop(c, 40);
        }
```

EDIT -----------

THIS IS MyBox.cs

```
    public partial class MyBox : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Header", typeof(string), typeof(MyBox),null);
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Content", typeof(string), typeof(MyBox), null);

        public string Header
        {
            get { return GetValue(HeaderProperty) as string; }
            set { SetValue(HeaderProperty, value); }
        }

        public string Text
        {
            get { return GetValue(TextProperty) as string; }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }

        public MyBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = this;

        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a typo (my mistake): should be "... TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text",..." Should not fix your issue but is a step in the right direction. :)

Comment: Check if you have some binding errors that appear in the output when you debug. And try to break in any method like an event handler and check the boxes, there is no reason they're not updated.

Comment: i've found the error, -> TextBox Text="{Binding Header,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}", the mode=twoway was missing.. thanks for the help again :)

Comment: btw, do you know a better way to connect the boxes? now i'm connecting them the way yo see in the picture, but when i move the boxes i need to move the connections separatedly.. that question is here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047624/make-line-that-connects-two-objects-in-silverlight

Comment: As for the binding this is because in Silverlight bindings default to OneWay whereas in WPF some bindings default to TwoWay like TextBox.Text because this is what you want 99% of the time. I was testing in WPF, not used SL since ... a while :)

Comment: do you know a way to import the xml file and update the canvas with the boxes and the info in them?

Comment: You just have to do the opposite: **parse an XDocument** from a String and recreate the boxes and connections, then add them to the Canvas. This is the same process you already use except this time all is done **in bulk**: you create all the items once, not on the fly. If you have some issue do not hesitate to open a new question. :)

Comment: can you give me a more explained or some examples? here is my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17222407/import-xml-and-update-canvas-silverlight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep track of all the boxes in a list:

```
IList<MyBox> boxes = new List<MyBox>();

private void b_ClickEntidade(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyBox c = new MyBox();
    c.Header = "Entidade";
    c.Text = "Atributos";

    ...

    boxes.Add(c);
}
```

Then generate the whole XML:

```
private XElement GetGeneratedXML()
{
    XElement userInformation = new XElement("names");

    foreach (MyBox b in boxes)
    {        
        userInformation.Add(new XElement("first", b.Text));
    }

    return userInformation;
}
```

Comment: that example is getting all the textboxes, the only problem is this "<names>
  <first>Atributos</first>
  <first>Atributos</first>
  <first>Atributos</first>
  <first>Atributos</first>
</names>"   ... it's getting the original textbox and not the editted one

Comment: So you changed the Text in the UI and you don't get it when XML serializing? Binding is two-way and real-time updated so should work...

Comment: yes, i edited the text but in the xml it appears as the original

Comment: I've tested it and it works fine. :( And I guess "b.Header" and all the other properties are not updated either? Please show more code.