# import xml and update canvas - silverlight

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, import

this image show what the project does

[image]

I can save the canvas to xml like this:

```
private void SaveFile(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog()
    {
        DefaultExt = "xml",
        Filter = "XML Files (*.xml)|*.xml|All files (*.*)|*.*",
        FilterIndex = 1
    };
    if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        using (Stream stream = saveFileDialog.OpenFile())
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                sw.Write(GetGeneratedXML().ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}

private XElement GetGeneratedXML()
{
    XElement userInformation = new XElement("Diagrama");
    foreach (MyBox b in boxes)
    {
        userInformation.Add(new XElement("Entidade",
            new XElement("Nome", b.Header),
            new XElement("Atributo", b.Text)));
    }
    foreach (Connection1 c in connections)
    {
        userInformation.Add(new XElement("Relação",
            new XElement("Entidade1",
                new XAttribute("Nome", c.Box1.Header),
                new XAttribute("Cardinalidade", c.Node1.Title)),
                new XElement("Entidade2",
                    new XAttribute("Nome", c.Box2.Header),
                    new XAttribute("Cardinalidade", c.Node2.Title)
                )
            )
        );
    }
    return userInformation;
}
```

And now, I would like to import this XML file and then update the Canvas with the boxes and connections. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a complete roundtrip that illustrates the process:

```
private static void TestGeneratedXML()
{
    MyBox livro = new MyBox { Header = "Livro", Text = "Nome\r\nAutor" };
    MyBox autor = new MyBox { Header = "Autor", Text = "Nome" };

    Connection hasAutors = new Connection
    {
        Box1 = livro,
        Box2 = autor,
        Node1 = new Node { Title = "1" },
        Node2 = new Node { Title = "*" }
    };

    MyBox[] boxes = { livro, autor };

    Connection[] connections = { hasAutors };

    XElement userInformation = new XElement("Diagrama");

    foreach (MyBox b in boxes)
    {
        userInformation.Add(new XElement("Entidade",
                                new XElement("Nome", b.Header),
                                new XElement("Atributo", b.Text)));
    }

    foreach (Connection c in connections)
    {
        userInformation.Add(new XElement("Relação",
                                new XElement("Entidade1",
                                    new XAttribute("Nome", c.Box1.Header),
                                    new XAttribute("Cardinalidade", c.Node1.Title)),
                                new XElement("Entidade2",
                                    new XAttribute("Nome", c.Box2.Header),
                                    new XAttribute("Cardinalidade", c.Node2.Title))));
    }

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

    XmlWriter xmlw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);// { Settings = new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true } };

    userInformation.WriteTo(xmlw);

    string xml = sw.ToString();

    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    MyBox[] outBoxes = doc.Root.Elements("Entidade")
                               .Select(e => new MyBox { Header = e.Element("Nome").Value, Text = e.Element("Atributo").Value })
                               .ToArray();

    Connection[] outConnections = doc.Root.Elements("Relação")
                                       .Select(e => new Connection
                                       {
                                           Box1 = outBoxes.Single(b => b.Header == e.Element("Entidade1").Attribute("Nome").Value),
                                           Box2 = outBoxes.Single(b => b.Header == e.Element("Entidade2").Attribute("Nome").Value),
                                           Node1 = new Node { Title = e.Element("Entidade1").Attribute("Cardinalidade").Value },
                                           Node2 = new Node { Title = e.Element("Entidade1").Attribute("Cardinalidade").Value },
                                           Line = new Line()
                                       })
                                       .ToArray();

    foreach (MyBox box in outBoxes)
    {
        box.MouseLeftButtonDown += Box_MouseLeftButtonDown;
        box.MouseLeftButtonUp += Box_MouseLeftButtonUp;
        box.MouseMove += Box_MouseMove;

        canvas.Children.Add(box);
    }

    RefreshLinesPositions();
}
```

Hope this helps...

**EDIT**: here is way to obtain the XML document from a file (to customize a little):

```
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
ofd.ShowDialog();

XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(ofd.FileName);
```

The user selects the file and it is loaded.

Comment: but this is for getting that example on the image, what i'm trying to do is getting a created xml file and update, your example is setting already the name to the boxes.. it should load the xml file and with the data update the canvas

Comment: Yes but this was only to illustrate with minimal plumbing. So you can skip the first part that creates the boxes and relations, and directly do something like: `string xml = File.ReadAllText("my_saved_data.xml")` or directly `XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("my_saved_data.xml")` :)

Comment: im not understanding, there is no open file or something? wich would open a window to select the xml file.. sorry im not very good at this :)

Comment: I've updated my answer, using the opposite of SaveFileDialog: **OpenFileDialog**.

Comment: i cant put this to work, im getting to many errors, and i dont really know what i have to cut (for that part "livro, autor") or where i have to put the openfiledialog.. it's saying that XmlTextWriter could not be found -> "XmlWriter xmlw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);"

Comment: You can skip all the code above `string xml = sw.ToString();` because you have already serialized the file in your *SaveFile* method. You just have to read the XML back from the file using an *OpenFileDialog*, then to create the *XDocument* from it as shown above.

Comment: i cant get through this "XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(ofd.Filename);" it says that filename could not be found

Comment: Debug and check the value of *FileName*, should be the **full path** of the file you've chosen when browsing.

Comment: when i debug it just give me this error "Error 1 'System.Windows.Controls.OpenFileDialog' does not contain a definition for 'Filename' and no extension method 'Filename' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.OpenFileDialog' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: hi, dont you know some other way? :) this is the final part of my project :)

Comment: The "Filename" issue is because you're using SL. Try `ofd.File.FullName` instead.

Comment: now when he trys to open the file it crashes with this error "File operation not permitted. Access to path '' is denied"

Comment: It your application is not full-trust use: `using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ofd.File.OpenRead())){ xml = reader.ReadToEnd(); }` then `XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);`

Comment: i have two doc files "XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);" and the " XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(ofd.File.FullName);", i tried without the parse(xml) but when i load the file nothing happens

Comment: Remove `XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(ofd.File.FullName);`

Comment: he's loading the boxes, but not the connections with the nodes (1,*)

Comment: You need to overwrite your list of connections: either do `connections = outConnections.ToList()` or directly assign: `connections = doc.Root.Elements("Relação").Select(e => new Connection{...}).ToList();`

Comment: yes, with that toList it works :D and i had to add this to the code, "foreach (Connection1 conn in connections)
            {
                LayoutRoot.Children.Add(conn.Node1);
                LayoutRoot.Children.Add(conn.Node2);
                LayoutRoot.Children.Add(conn.Line); }"

Comment: do you know some way the save the position of the items? because when i load the file it appears all random, for the boxes it's no problem, but the nodes (1;*) i dont know which node is for what box

Comment: To obtain the position of any item relative to your canvas use: `Point position = node.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), canvas);`

Comment: but with this i'm getting the first position of the node, without the moving

Comment: Please avoid extended discussions in the comments.

Comment: do you know how to get the last position of the object? after the last move get his position.. i can make a new question

Comment: If you can position your boxes and connections what's the issue with nodes? They are positioned relative to the connections, no?

Comment: the nodes can be dragged freely.. if there is some way to get the nodes always close to the connections that would be some other alternative, that way, when the xml loads the nodes would be close to the connection

Comment: The connections are positioned relatively to the boxes, so you can do the same for the nodes positioning them relatively to the connections, e.g. just above them, in the *RefreshLinesPositions* method.

Comment: i'm trying to do something like RefreshLinesPositions but i cant understand the code you did